# Return early from long-running POST in Node/Express

Tags: node.js, express, publish-subscribe, cqrs, mediator

I'm new to Node/Express. I have a long-running series of processes, for example:  `post to Express endpoint -> save data (can return now) -> handle data -> handle data -> handle data -> another process -> etc.`

A typical POST:

```
app.post("/foo", (req, res) => {
  // save data and return
  return res.send("200");
  // but now I want to do a lot more stuff...
});
```

If I omit the `return` then more processing will occur, but even though I' a newbie to this stack, I can tell that's a bad idea.

All I want is to receive some data, save it and return. Then I want to start processing it, and call into other processes, which call into other processes, etc. I don't want the original POST to wait for all this to complete.

*I need to do this in-process*, so I can't save to a queue and process it separately afterwards.

*Basically I want to DECOUPLE the receipt and processing of the data, in process.*

What options are available using Node/Express?

Comment: This depends on your case. Do you really want to make frontend unaware whether 'more stuff' completed successfully or not?

Comment: @estus Yes the caller does not need to know... just dump data and get a response that the save worked. In a bigger system that would be a good place to have a out-of-proc queue and some batch processing, but in this system that is not possible, so I'm curious how experienced Express people would solve this problem?

Comment: Then early 202 response as the answer suggests fits the case IMO.

Comment: @estus Thanks estus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with your approach of removing `return` here and ending the request.....so long as you don't have any other code that tries to send any data back later on.

I'd recommend returning status code [202 Accepted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/202) for these long running scenarios though, this indicates to the consumer that the server has accepted the request but it's not finished.

Comment: Yeah it works, and if that's the only option then I'll grudgingly use it. But lots of experience tells me that's a very bad design. Is that approach idiomatic for Node/Express? - I'm new to it so I don't know what is considered "normal".

Comment: @lonix could you give me an example of why it's bad design - I'm struggling to see what the issue is myself? Express is a simply an HTTP layer over your application, ending the request early and processing on is perfectly acceptable to me, it won't affect other requests.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I may have to do it this way. I want to leave the question open for a while longer though, to see if there are more ideas...

Comment: @lonix FWIW I've built a large scale application, currently out in production, using this approach. I made more use of middleware to keep things clean but the approach is the same - finish the request early, continue to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: Moving to a new stack is not just about the theory, it's also about completely different idioms - so thanks James, I appreciate your insights.

Answer (score 7):

I'd try something like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const port = 3000;
const app = express();
const uuid = require('uuid');

app.post("/foo", (req, res) => {
    const requestId = uuid.v4();
    // Send result. Set status to 202: The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.3.3.
    res.status(202).json({ status: "Processing data..", requestId: requestId });

    // Process request.
    processRequest(requestId, request);
});

app.get("/fooStatus", (req, res) => {
    // Check the status of the request.
    let requestId = req.body.requestId;

});

function processRequest(requestId, request) {
    /* Process request here, then perhaps save result to db. */
}

app.listen(port);
console.log(`Serving at http://localhost:${port}`);
```

Calling this with curl (for example):

```
curl -v -X POST http://localhost:3000/foo
```

Would give a response like:

```
{"status":"Processing data..","requestId":"abbf6a8e-675f-44c1-8cdd-82c500cbbb5e"}
```

Comment: Yes I know how to do this, but I'm curious to know 1) is there a better way?, and 2) since you are experienced with Express, is this how you would do it? Is it possible to use in-process pub-sub, for example and decouple the two processes?

Comment: 1) It depends on how resource intensive your processing is. Will it take seconds, minutes, hours. You don't want to delay a request by a long period of time, therefore a 202 may be Ok in this context.  2). There are several ways of processing REST calls in an asynchronous way, you could use a queuing mechanism such a MQTT / AMQP,.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I may have to do it this way. I want to leave the question open for a while longer though, to see if there are more ideas...

Comment: Would this be a place I could use "RXJS" or some observer pattern library? I've not used rxjs it so I don't know if it fits.

Comment: No problem! A common pattern would be to save the request to a data store or queue along with a unique id (which means a uuid effectively). Return the id to the caller along with the id and provide a REST API for them to check the status of the processing, e.g. "IN-PROGRESS", "COMPLETE", "FAILURE" etc. Once processing is complete they can retrieve the result with another GET call.

Comment: I'm not sure if RXJS would be a good fit here, I've only used in on client-side JavaScript code.

Comment: Another option is a CQRS mediator pattern, but it's overkill for my particular need in this case. Thanks for your insights, I appreciate it!